# Solve a recurrence relation with two recursion calls using the iteration method

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

I can't figure out how to solve this recurrence relation using the iteration method:

$$T(n) =
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if $n=0$} \\
1, & \text{if $n=1$} \\
3T(n-1)+ 4T(n-2),  & \text{if $n >1$} 
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $S(n) = T(n+1) + T(n)$. We have $S(0) = 1$, and for $n > 0$,
$$ S(n) = T(n+1) + T(n) = [3T(n) + 4T(n-1)] + T(n) = 4(T(n) + T(n-1)) = 4S(n-1). $$
Can you take it from here?